# Ceiling lamp makes clicking sound after switching on lights?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling

[image: ceiling lamp that makes noise]

I turn it on, it right away makes a metalic click coming from ceiling. It then at times continues to make that same sound irregularly, even after turning off the lights. I can't sleep because of it. It stops after an hour.

Facts about the ceiling lamp:

- it's not sitting flush on the ceiling, because an old metalic hook pokes out of the ceiling right where the lamp is. The   flat plate can be tipped from side to side because it's resting on the hook. The flat plate is screwed to ceiling but  not flush all the way because of the hook.
- it's cheap Chinese lamp
- the power cable feed to the switch outlet is only 1mm size, but the cable going to the ceiling is bigger.
- 3 ikea led lights (600lm each)

Comment: You haven't explicitly asked a question.

Comment: If it's just cheap junk from china then just replace it and move on.

Comment: Im not sure if the lamp is responsible, and replacing wont be easy, would need to drill and remove obstructions, which i never done before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to hear that you have a ticking sound, possible heat expansion.  It is clearly not installed properly with old support eye still in place.  I recommend a complete proper redo of hanging of the fixture.  Make sure all connections are clean and tight. Get all obstructions out of the way.  And no pinched wires.

Comment: I agree.  Doing it right is the best way to be able to sleep soundly.

Comment: Whats cause of heat expansion? im not an electrician, and an electrician did this and other rooms, but the lights in the other rooms blew up and didnt work so we made him redo (wanted more money for it). Not confident in bringing him back. What can i do to quickly resolve this? i cant get obstruction out of the way, the metal is almost part of the ceiling. Whats pinched wires?